# Nginx Disable Basic Auth - Laravel Forge

Tags: nginx, http-basic-authentication

On a Laravel Forge Nginx Server I've enabled basic auth security at a root level for my site, this is working fine.

However I'm now trying to exclude a webhooks path from basic auth to allow the site to function properly with third parties.

No matter what I try this it not seem to work, it works fine if the folder/file exists in the filesystem but not for pretty URLs set-up as routes in Laravel.

This is an extract of my nginx configuration file:

```
auth_basic "Restricted Area";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/forge-conf/mywebsite/server/.htpasswd;

location = /hooks/stripe {  
    auth_basic "off";
    allow all;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

The above works fine if I change `/hooks/stripe` to a physical file such as my CSS or favicon. Additionally inverting it works without issue, where I can lock just that route with a password.

I've tried using variations of the location block, some with `=` and some without. Additionally I've tried `auth_basic off;` and removing `allow all;`. Finally i've tried changing the location using different modifiers and making it less specific and placing it before and after the `/` root location `try_files`.

Any help would be massively appreciated as I'm now completely stuck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable basic auth sitewide and disabling it for subpages?](https://serverfault.com/questions/330580/enable-basic-auth-sitewide-and-disabling-it-for-subpages)

Comment: The answer doesn't itself but the example they use does show another approach of moving the auth requirements into the location block. This doesn't match the documentation as a requirement but is working... https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/#configuring-nginx-and-nginx-plus-for-http-basic-authentication 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@AlexD](https://serverfault.com/users/23022/alexd) suggestion in the comments the below works, however you have to move the forge import which may have unintended impacts.

If you try to access a URL that doesn't exist, `/hooks/lost` you still get the basic auth request which I'm unsure why but for now this solves the immediate problem.

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
#include forge-conf/mywebsite/server/*;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    include forge-conf/mywebsite/server/*;
}

location /hooks {  
    auth_basic off;
}
```